# Global variable in Kotlin (android studio) initialized in one activity remains at initialized value in other activities

Tags: android, kotlin, global-variables

I would like to implement a global variable that updates its value when going from one activity to another (and back). To explain in better detail, let's say my variable is called globalVar, and globalVar is initialized in activity A as "", then within activity A, when a couple of buttons are pressed, the value is updated to a new string. When going from activity A to activity B, globalVar at activity B should be equal to the updated string in activity A in addition to some value. In other words, globaVar should be keeping track of its updates.

The problem is that when I'm going from one activity to another, the value of my global variable is resetting itself to its initialized value.

I have already tried making the initialization private, and implementing a public function that updates the value but that didn't work. Below is the code that I have.

```kotlin
public class Speak : AppCompatActivity(){

    private var globalVar= ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_speak)

        val pplMom= findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.pplMom)
         globalVar= "mom" 

       pplMom.setOnClickListener{

        intent= Intent(this, People::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)}} 
        
    public fun setVar (globalVar :String) {

        this.globalVar= globalVar
        Toast.makeText(this, globalVar, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    }
    public fun getVar(): String {

        return globalVar
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class People: AppCompatActivity(),  {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_people)

      
        var mApp= Speak()
        var globalVar= mApp.getVar()
        globalVar= globalVar + "testtest"

        Toast.makeText(this, globalVar, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

}}
```

What I have printed is "testtest" instead of "Hellotesttest"

Comment: This is not the proper way to start an activity. If you just want to store some data in some sort of globally-accessible object, don't use an activity class for that. But you may want to think about why you want to do this in the first place. Do you really need a global variable? If there is no other way to get around it, this might be an acceptable use case for SharedPreferences, but normally what you're trying should not be necessary

Comment: I am using activity classes because each activity corresponds to a different page with different code (there is a necessity for me to to do this) it's just that I don't see it relevant to explain the whole project I'm working on here and simply substituted what I had with simple code. I will look into SharedPrefernces and see if that solves my problem